# install a VTK (graphing library) with support for python 2.7 / win32

Tags: windows, python

How should I install VTK (vtk.org) on windows xp in such way so it possible to use it from python 2.7 with module "vtk" (it is requirement by scitools)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get an executable for Windows (32 and 64 bits) with VTK and the Python wrapper for VTK, for Python 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7 here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#vtk.

Good luck